# How to translate IQueryable to List of a Custom Class?

Tags: c#, .net, database, list, linq

This question is based on a dotnet@2.1 MVC Application.

I have the following function which should return a **List** of some class I made.
Does anyone know how I can translate the IQueryable to a list? I have tried ToList(). But it still gives me a convert error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'Model.Book[]'
>   [firstChance-2nd-attempt]csharp(CS0029)

**LibraryController.cs**

```cs
        [HttpGet("GetAuthorsAndBooks")]
        public AuthorBooks[] GetAuthorsAndBooks()
        {
            //TODO 6: missing code 1pt
            var authorsAndBooks = (
              from a in _context.Authors
              let bookList = (
                from ba in _context.BookAuthor
                where ba.AuthorId == a.Id
                join b in _context.Books on ba.BookId equals b.Id
                select new { Id = b.Id, Title = b.Title, Year = b.Year }
              )
              select new AuthorBooks { Author = a, Books = bookList.ToList() }
            );

            return authorsAndBooks; // ! CONVERT ERROR
        }
        public class AuthorBooks
        {
            public Author Author { get; set; }
            public Book[] Books { get; set; }
        }
```

> Thanks to @Phong it works. See the modified **LibraryController.cs** below.

**LibraryController.cs [solution]**

```cs
        [HttpGet("GetAuthorsAndBooks")]
        public AuthorBooks[] GetAuthorsAndBooks()
        {
            //TODO 6: missing code 1pt
            var authorsAndBooks = (
              from a in _context.Authors
              let bookList = (
                from ba in _context.BookAuthor
                where ba.AuthorId == a.Id
                join b in _context.Books on ba.BookId equals b.Id
                select new Book { Id = b.Id, Title = b.Title, Year = b.Year }
              )
              select new AuthorBooks { Author = a, Books = bookList.ToArray() }
            ).ToArray();

            return authorsAndBooks;
        }
        public class AuthorBooks
        {
            public Author Author { get; set; }
            public Book[] Books { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: `But it still gives me a convert error.` You should show us the error you are getting.

Comment: ```Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Id, string Title, System.DateTime Year>>' to 'Model.Book[]' [firstChance-2nd-attempt]csharp(CS0029)```

Comment: Consider reading the error message you're getting in more detail - It's pointing out that your anonymous class creation in your `select` clause can't be converted to a `Book` *and* that `List<Book>` cannot be converted to `Book[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to get rid of the error

- Declare `List` instead of `Array` type

  ```
  public class AuthorBooks
  {
      public Author Author { get; set; }
      public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- `Books = bookList.ToArray()` instead.

**Updated**

You are selecting `anonymous type` at here

```
select new { Id = b.Id, Title = b.Title, Year = b.Year }
```

So you should select `new Book` instead, Like this

```
select new Book { Id = b.Id, Title = b.Title, Year = b.Year }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I may no change the AuthorBooks class. So I changed ToList() to ToArray(). Still getting an error:
```<anonymous type: int Id, string Title, DateTime Year>[] IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int Id, string Title, DateTime Year>>.ToArray<<anonymous type: int Id, string Title, DateTime Year>>()
Creates an array from a System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 .

Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: int Id, string Title, System.DateTime Year>[]' to 'Model.Book[]' [firstChance-2nd-attempt]csharp(CS0029)```

Comment: `select new Book { Id = b.Id, Title = b.Title, Year = b.Year }`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please take a look @ @Steven Soekha

Comment: Aah Thanks @Phong it works! I've implemented your suggestions and added one final ToArray() on the authorAndBooks. I will update this post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `IQueryable<AuthorBooks>` interface is a different type than `List<AuthorBooks>`.  The first issue is that your method is returning the type `AuthorBooks[]`, which is also a different type than your desired return type of `List<AuthorBooks>`.

If you wish the method `GetAuthorsAndBooks()` to return `List<AuthorBooks>`, first change its return type appropriately.

Then in the code, your `return` statement is currently returning the variable `authorsAndBooks`.  The assignment of this variable is via a LINQ query, which results in the type `IQueryable<AuthorBooks>`.  The `IQueryable<T>` interface implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.  These interfaces are designed to allow conversion of mostly any `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` to many other collection types.  One of those is methods allows you to convert to `List<T>`.  And that is available via the method `ToList()`.  (Note that if for some reason you still want to keep the existing return type as `AuthorBooks[]`, then you could convert to an array instead of List, by using the `ToArray()` method instead of `ToList()`.)

Note that you need to import `System.Linq` in your code to be able to use these methods, if you haven't already done so.

Definition of `IQueryable<T>` (see that it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=netframework-4.8#definition

Definition of the `ToList()` method available in `IEnumerable<T>`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8

NOTE: Technically, the interface `IEnumerable<T>` itself does not implement the `ToList()` method, and is not even part of the actual interface.  Instead this is actually defined on a static class `Enumerable` using "extension methods".

APPENDIX: For additional fun, you can actually look at the underlying source code of the `ToList()` method itself in the .NET Framework here:

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs